# Adding a TGlowEffect to a derived firemonkey TImage component

Tags: delphi

I have a component that I have derived from TImage that has TGlowEffect. I have it installed and it is visible on the form. I can change the glow effect parameters but when I run the program the program crashes Rad Studio?

Here is my code.

```
type
   TGlowImage = class( TImage )  
   private  
       FGlowEffect: TGlowEffect;  

       procedure SetGlowEffect( const Value : TGlowEffect );  

    protected

    public
      constructor Create( AOwner : TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy(); override;

    published
      property GlowEffect : TGlowEffect read FGlowEffect write SetGlowEffect;
    end;

procedure Register;  

implementation  

procedure Register;  
  begin  
    RegisterComponents( 'SomeCompany', [TGlowImage] );  
  end;  

{ TGlowImage }  

constructor TGlowImage.Create( AOwner : TComponent );  
  begin  
    inherited;  
      FGlowEffect := TGlowEffect.Create( Self )  
  end;  

destructor TGlowImage.Destroy();  
  begin  
    if( Assigned( FGlowEffect ) ) then  
      FreeAndNil( FGlowEffect );  
    inherited;  
  end;  

procedure TGlowImage.SetGlowEffect( const Value : TGlowEffect );  
  begin  
    FGlowEffect.Assign( Value );  
  end;
```

I don't know what I have missed but it must be rather bad.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "the program crashes RAD Studio" is not a useful problem description. Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say? Don't install components until you've tested them. You do so by creating it in code in a test app, and setting the parameters to different values; if it doesn't work, you can easily use the debugger to determine why. Once you've thoroughly tested it, *then* you install it.

Comment: Not the cause of the crash but in your destructor there is no need to call Assigned before FreeAndNil. FreeAndNil can safely be called with a nil reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you cannot assign [TGlowEffect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/de/FMX.Effects.TGlowEffect) to [TGlowEffect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/de/FMX.Effects.TGlowEffect). If you run the code you will get an EConvertError Exception (TGlowEffect cannot assigned to TGlowEffect).
I think you can use just a standard [TImage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Objects.TImage) and add the TGlowEffect as ChildComponent or you should implement the TGlowEffect as an readonly property, so you can access the properties of the effect.

```
TGlowImage=class(TImage)
private
  FGlowEffect: TGlowEffect;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy(); override;
published
  property GlowEffect: TGlowEffect read FGlowEffect;
end;

{ TGlowImage }

constructor TGlowImage.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FGlowEffect:=TGlowEffect.Create(Self);
  Self.AddObject(FGlowEffect);
end;

destructor TGlowImage.Destroy();
begin
  FreeAndNil(FGlowEffect);
  inherited;
end;
```